The address EPjFWdd5AufqSSqeM2qN1xzybapC8G4wEGGkZwyTDt1v is invalid; the checksum test failed or it's an unconvertible IBAN address
I’m running into an issue with a Solana address: EPjFWdd5AufqSSqeM2qN1xzybapC8G4wEGGkZwyTDt1v. When I try to use it, I receive the following error message:
"The capitalization checksum test failed, or it’s an indirect IBAN address which can’t be converted."
I’ve already double-checked for any typos and even validated the address on Sol scan. Everything seems correct, but the error persists. Has anyone encountered this issue before, or does anyone have suggestions on how to resolve it?
Thanks in advance for any guidance you can offer!

Where are you seeing that error message? Your address is the correct mainnet USDC mint address. I think the issue is you’re using it in a field that does not expect a Solana address, but I don’t know where you’re using it to know for sure.

This problem appears when we use Phantom to connect to the Solana wallet and choose a token.
Thanks.

In a specific app, or in Phantom? On which platform? Please give as many details as you can

When we connect phantom wallet and choose solana token at a time , the following error message appears: Provided address EPjFWdd5AufqSSqeM2qN1xzybapC8G4wEGGkZwyTDt1v is invalid, the capitalization checksum test failed, or it's an indirect IBAN address that cannot be converted.
